# Unable to contact valid Reprository Publisher on Solaris11

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, solaris-11

on my just install Solaris11 on Oracle VM, I got this at startup: Unable to contact valid reprository publisher. application/pkg/server:default failed AUTO-RESPONSE: The service has been placed into the maintenance state.

Is there anyone with experience in Solaris 11 who could shed some light on what could be done.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The application/pkg/server:default service instance is not enabled by default.  How was this VM installed?

It sounds like there was some configuration performed.

Are you certain that was the name of the service that failed?